# Get Excel 2016 on Mac to stop interpreting my formulas as text?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

When I enter the following formula on Excel 2016 for Mac and press enter, Mac left adjusts the content of the cell and sets the formatting to text. If I edit the cell again and click on enter, Excel prints the formula in the cell instead of calculating it and printing the value.

```
=INDEX(Sweden!$A:$X;MATCH($A10;Sweden!$A:$A;0);MATCH(B$2;Sweden!$2:$2;0))+INDEX(USA!$A:$X;MATCH($A10;USA!$A:$A;0);MATCH(B$2;Sweden!$2:$2;0))+INDEX(UK!$A:$X;MATCH($A10;UK!$A:$A;0);MATCH(B$2;Sweden!$2:$2;0))+INDEX(International!$A:$X;MATCH($A10;International!$A:$A;0);MATCH(B$2;Sweden!$2:$2;0))
```

What triggers this strange behaviour? How can I stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to preferences >> view. This will bring up a load of tick-boxes.
If one of them called "formulas" is ticked, then that will trigger this behaviour.

Comment: Goos idea, but that ckeckbox is not ticked